# Efficient way to sort and return ranks in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, coronasdk

Say i have millions of players and their scores, when ever a user (can multiple user requesting at different interval) request for the rank it should return his rank.

So the problem here is when requesting only once there wont be any problem , suppose say thousands of users requesting their rankings at the same time, the DB may crash. Is there a way to sort out.

And more over my Db is real time DB, where score will be updated real-time when the player completes a game.

EDIT:

Is this right approach for my problem or it has any flaws - [Efficient way to SELECT a fixed range of high scores given only a user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996899/efficient-way-to-select-a-fixed-range-of-high-scores-given-only-a-user-id?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thank you

Comment: If the score is updated once a while can make sense let this data at player record the rank can be a indexed (by the score) view this will consume disk but fetching  this data will not be a big problem. If there's millions players the rank can be done as an "estimative" just get it's rank at the time it scored and decrease it based in a overtime function. Fro pratical reason only the top 100/1000 really needs to be real time updated

Comment: I don't think multiple simultaneous reads can cause DB to crash, unless there are large write operations are going on and locking tables you should be good with multiple simultaneous reads. If later is the case then I would suggest you a materialized view with short update intervals or another staging table which you can update at regular intervals.

Comment: The worst you should get, if there is no deadlock problem, would be a poor performance. But the whole point of a dbms like mysql is to be able to handle  lots of simultaneous connections. Maybe if you are scaling to the millions of user you could use some premium version and/or hosting.

Comment: @NiranjanRajawat i am not going to do any write operation, i am going to do only the read operation and sorting for the ranks,

Comment: @KumarKS : Then in a practical world using a well known DBMS, you should not have any problem.

Comment: "Is this right approach for my problem or it has any flaws - Efficient way to SELECT a fixed range of high scores given only a user id"  hard to say.. your query will need good indexing to be efficient with millions off records.